# An inequality concerning restricted isometry property

Tags: inequalities, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a matrix and let us denote by $A_S$ the submatrix of $A$ with the columns restricted to a set $S\subset [n]:=\{1,2,\cdots, \ n\}$. Then one says that the matrix $A$ has [restricted isometry property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_isometry_property) of order $K$ with constant $\delta_K$ if the matrix $A$ has the property $$\delta_K=\max_{S\subset[n]:|S|\le K}\|A_S^TA_S-I\|_{2\to 2}$$

There is a very nice Cauchy-Scwartz like inequality concerning this constant which can be stated as below

> If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $supp(x)\subset S_1,\ supp(y)\subset S_2,\ S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$, then, 
>   $$|\langle Ax,Ay\rangle |< \delta_{|S_1|+|S_2|} \|x\|_2\|y\|_2$$

Emmanuel Candes proved this inequality [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RIP.pdf). The proof is rather simple.

I am trying to find a similar inequality, for the quantity in the LHS, but now a lower bound and also with the constraint $S_1\cap S_2\ne \emptyset$. I do not know if it is trivially $0$, but I hope it is not. I have still not succeeded to find it. I have searched for such an inequality in the literature but failed to get one.

So it will be really helpful if anyone can direct me either towards some relevant literature or giving some helpful tips to come up with a non-trivial lower bound. Thanks in advance.

I asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080396/an-inequality-concerning-restricted-isometry-property) also but I did not get any answer.

Comment: If you only have $supp(x) \subset S_1$ and $supp(y) \subset S_2$ then  no lower bound greater than zero is to be expected and even if you have non-trivial intersection of the supports then the inner product can well be zero, I guess.